# How to insert many values in arrays efficiently (with C++17 or earlier)?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

Given an array with a size with m entries having size of 3: `n = m * 3`. On every position after `m` values a new value should be inserted that the size is afterwards `n = m * 4`. [image]

My naive approach would be to create a larger array with the new size and than iterate over the arrays copying the values into the new one and every m steps to add another step for the new-array-iteration and filling in the new value. 
The example code below might help understanding what I try to achieve.

I guess this might not be efficient. Unfortunately this array interleaving is carried out often. Therefore, the code should be efficient to avoid long computing times.

What are some other stategies and are there tools in the current standard library to use? The example uses an array but I am open to other containers.

**Edit: Example code**

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    const auto arrSize = 52428800; // entries for the initial array
    auto arr = new double[arrSize * 3]; // 3 sequential elements are a group

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for( auto i = 0; i < arrSize*3; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = 1.0*i/arrSize;
    }

    auto larr = new double[arrSize * 4]; // larger array with space for interleaving elements

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp for
    for (auto i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) // after each element group of three a new element should be inserted
    {
        auto k = 0;
        auto j = i*3;
        for(k=0; k < 3; ++k)
        {
            larr[i*4+k] = arr[j+k];
        }
        larr[i*4+k] = 0;
    }

    delete[] arr;
    delete[] larr;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you *know* it's going to be frequent, then maybe an array isn't the correct container to begin with? Perhaps a linked list would be a better choice?

Comment: Do you insert the new elements as a single step? So every "\*3" grows to "\*4" at once? Or in *m* steps, but ordered (first element grows first, *m*th last)? What about access of existing elements? Do you want to access a single element at a time? Or a single "stride" ("\*3", "\*4")? Arbitrary number of elements? How often?

Comment: It does not matter if the array grows at one or stepwise. The array elements are not changed during the resizing. They might be only accessed for the resizing purpose. How many elements are handled at a time is arbitrary. The number of running the resizing is probably in the thousands (i do not have an single number). After the resizing the elements are handled in strides of 4.

Comment: This problem is not worded particularly clearly. It starts out looking like you have `std::array< /* 3-byte type */, m>` (an array with `m` entries, each of size 3), but then what is this "every position after `m`"? Inserting a new (3-byte) value causes the values to increase to 4 bytes each? And what is this `a` subscript?

Perhaps you could supplement your question with some declarations to illustrate what we're dealing with? It might also be useful to go into why an array was chosen instead of another container.

Comment: @JaMiT I added a piece of code to clarifiy my problem. The `a` subscript is just an running index to make the description more general.

Answer (score 1):

Do your elements *need* to be sequential in memory? If not you can have a vector of vectors and do the interleaving when accessing the vectors.

Personally, I would use a custom container class that wraps a `vector< vector<foo>>`:

```
template <class T>
class interleaved_vector 
{
    std::vector< std::vector <T> > data;

  public:
    void interleave(const std::vector <T> & v)
    {
       data.push_back(v);
    }

    /* I am a little bit rusty on move-semantics, so I don't guarantee this is 
       correct */
    void interleave(std::vector &&v)
    {
       data.push_back(std::move(v));
    }

    // Access the data in an interleaved way
    // This assumes all the interleaved vectors have the same size.
    T operator[] (size_t i) const
    {
       size_t i1 = i / data.front().size();
       size_t i2 = i % data.front().size();

       return data[i1][i2];
    }

    T & operator[] (size_t i)
    {
       size_t i1 = i / data.front().size();
       size_t i2 = i % data.front().size();

       return data[i1][i2];
    }

 }
```

Now, you can declare a container of interleaved `int`s:

```
interleaved_vector<int> iv;

// populate the vector 

std::vector<int> v(m)

iv.interleave(v);
iv.interleave(v);
iv.interleave(v);

// populate it using move-semantic
iv.interleave(std::move(v));

// read the n-th element after interleaving
int i = iv[n];

// set the n-th element after interleaving 
iv[n] = 1234;
```

This is not a complete container class, just a generic idea. It lacks iterators etc.... How to complete it, and better fit it to your use-case, is left as an exercise to the reader